# Android missing Gen File

Tags: android

My android gen file all of a sudden disappeared. I have tried using Clean to regenerate it, but nothing is happening. I also tried restarting eclipse. Any suggestions?

Comment: your code, xmls have no errors? gen file (R) normally "dissapears" when there is an error in the proyect.

Comment: There were no errors, but I removed a giant string from my strings.xml file and it fixed the problem.

Comment: In the future you can try running Lint check, sometimes it can catch misc errors like the on you had.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Project` Tab -> Check `Build Automatically` in eclipse.